# Is there a way to place override function in a separate file in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a Kotlin class that is becoming very large (a couple of hundreds of lines). It's mainly because this class is the listener of several interfaces. Usually, I split my class functions with extensions (and place them in separate files). However, when I try that with override functions, Android Studio gives me this error:

> "Modifier 'override' is not applicable to 'top level function'"

So, is there a workaround? How would you split a large file with many override functions? (In Swift, this is done using extensions or Partials in C#). Here is an image for reference in Android Studio and in Xcode. In Swift, we simply add "extension" and that allows us to write code as if we were writing right within the class:

[image]

Comment: why do you have an interface and your abstract class declared in the same file ? wouldn't it help your cause to create these in different files to begin with ?

Comment: well override only works on class/objects in this case override is not usable or maybe can you point why you want to apply outside class or the reference which points how its done in swift of c#

Comment: @a_local_nobody everything is written in separate files. This was done for the purpose of demonstration.

Comment: Extension functions are not part of extended classes body, they're just syntactic sugar for static functions. You probably need to redesign your class and break it into pieces as it seems you're creating a god-object.

Comment: @AnaniyaJemberu I updated the question to show the differences. The reason I want to place them in separate files, is simply to make the code more organized and readable.

Comment: Can you post your class please?

Comment: @NitinPrakash unfortunately the code is proprietary. It's basically an Activity class that is the listener for several other objects (more than 10). This is a graphics application, so imagine things such as color pickers, selectors, transformations, etc. So, because of that, this one class has to handle many different functions through listeners.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of having your Activity implement listener interfaces, make them into anonymous object members. I think this is usually cleaner anyway.

```
class MyActivity: AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var binding: MyActivityBinding
    private val someButtonListener = OnClickListener {
        binding.text = "Button clicked!"
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = MyActivityBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        binding.button.onClickListener = someButtonListener
    }
}
```

Then, you could break these out into another file by making functions that create them.

```
class MyActivity: AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var binding: MyActivityBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = MyActivityBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        binding.button.onClickListener = createSomeButtonListener(binding)
    }
}

fun createSomeButtonListener(binding: MyActivityBinding) = OnClickListener {
    binding.text = "Button clicked!"
}
```

If you need to call functions in the Activity from these listeners, you'll have to make your Activity a parameter of the function and expose those functions as public, unfortunately. It's not really proper encapsulation, but you typically don't reference Activities from other classes ever, so it's probably not a big deal for it to have some public functions.

Comment: Your solution actually put me on the right track. Using an anonymous object listener would actually make my life a lot easier. I accepted your answer and posted my example inspired by it as well.

Answer (score 0):

This is my code inspired by the answer:

```
interface MyInterface {
    fun itHappened()
}

class MyClass {
    lateinit var listener: MyInterface
}

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val myObj = MyClass()
        myObj.listener = anonymousListener()
        myObj.listener.itHappened()
    }
}

fun MainActivity.anonymousListener() = object : MyInterface {
    override fun itHappened() {
        Log.d("MyTag", "Clicked")
    }
}
```

Comment: A tip: if you declare your interface as a `fun interface`, you can create one using a lambda, so your function at the bottom would just be `fun MainActivity.anonymousListener() = MyInterface { Log.d("MyTag", "Clicked") }`

Comment: @Tenfour04 that's a great tip. I honestly didn't know you can make `fun interface`.